# How to overlap two images and place them at the bottom of mobile screen?

Tags: html, css

I have two overlapping images in a div that I want to place at the bottom of the mobile responsive page, but I'm having Issues with white space at the end of the page and I'm not sure what to use.

my HTML:

```
       <div id="wrapper">
        <img id="purpleMobile" src="./assets/purpleMobile.svg" alt="Purple" />
        <img id="rocketMobile" src="./assets/rocketMobile.svg" alt="Rocket" />
       </div>
```

CSS:

```
  #wrapper {
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 1;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: auto;
  }
  #rocketMobile {
    left: 0%;
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
  }
  #purpleMobile {
    right: 0%;
    bottom: 0;
    position: relative;
  }
```

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_backgrounds.asp - use 2 background images, the background image that should be dispalyed on top of the other has to be called first.

Comment: @tacoshy For some reason I still have the same issue as before

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a reset in your css. You could try adding this to your css.

```
 body {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }
```

Argus

Comment: still not working, but thanks for the idea I'll try playing around

Comment: So it still has whitespace?

Comment: Yup still does have whitespace